# Fetching database data from angular

Tags: database

Is it possible to fetch database data directly from Front end app(Angular or any other) with out server?

I am not getting any idea to try.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need a server of some kind, whether it's Java, C#, NodeJS, or something like GraphQL.

Let me clarify something, remember that your Angular and React run in Javascript, which run on the user's browser, on the user's computer, whereas the backend code runs on your server which you have a lot of control over. The browser is very much a sandbox and has only limited capabilities due to security concerns and it's development over the years.

Now, you could say, that someone has a API that you can consume without a database server - however, you are probably still not talking to their database server, you're talking to their back-end app server.

There are many services out there such as AWS, Firebase, which can provide this, and are dubbed "Serverless" because the main construct is an application or service, rather than a server.. But somewhere, there's a server.